# Load XML from Project directory

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have Windows Forms Application; which tries to load an XML file and insert the name property of the nodes into a combobox. The application tries to look for the XML file in the dicebag\bin\Debug folder but the file is in the dicebag folder. how can I make this file include in the application or change the location of where it looks for the file? Currently I recieve this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Troy Pilewski\Source\Repositories\dicebag\bin\Debug\dice.xml'.

[image]

Comment: Put data in the `Users` folders, that is what they are for (see `Environment.GetFolderPath()`.  Those debug folders are part of VS, not the app setup

Comment: What users folders? How do I do this?

Comment: Set Build Action: Content and Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always and Set Publish Options to Include still not working...